# How to cache only part of the RDD in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, caching

I have a `PairRDD<Metadata, BigData>`.

I want to do two actions: one on all the data in the `RDD` and then another action on only the Metadata.

The input comes from reading massive files, which I don't want to repeat.

I understand that the classic thing to do is to use `cache()` or `persist()` on the input RDD so that it is kept in memory:

```
JavaPairRDD<Metadata, Bigdata> inputRDD = expensiveSource();
JavaPairRDD<Metadata, Bigdata> cachedRDD = inputRDD.cache();
cachedRDD.foreach(doWorkOnAllData);
cachedRDD.keys().foreach(doWorkOnMetadata);
```

The problem is that the input is so big that it doesn't fit in memory and `cache()` therefore does not do anything.

I could use `persist()` to cache it on a disk but since the data is so big, saving and reading all that data will actually be slower than reading the original source.

I could use `MEMORY_SERDE` to gain a bit of space, but it is probably not enough, and even then serializing the whole thing when I am just interested in 0.1% of the data seems silly.

What I want is to cache only the key part of my `PairRDD`. I thought I could do that by calling `cache()` on the `keys()` `RDD`:

```
JavaPairRDD<Metadata, Bigdata> inputRDD = expensiveSource();
JavaRDD<Metadata, Bigdata> cachedRDD = inputRDD.keys().cache();
inputRDD.foreach(doWorkOnAllData);
cachedRDD.foreach(doWorkOnMetadata);
```

But in that case it doesn't seem to cache anything, and just go back to load the source.

Is it possible to only put a part of the data in cache? The operation on the metadata is ridiculously small but I have to do it after the operation on the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

Spark will only load you RDD from cache if you call `inputRDD.keys()`

What you can try is : `JavaRDD<Metadata> keys = inputRDD.keys().cache();` to cache your `JavaRDD<Metadata>`

Then to make your cachedRDD you do :

```
JavaRDD<Metadata,Bigdata> cachedRDD = keys.join(JavaPairRDD<Bigdata>)
```

Also if you RDD is huge, read from cache is slowest the first time because you have to save your RDD, but the next time to read it, it will be faster.